# Grid Layout for Calendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, calendar, css-tables

I need to make a basic calendar display for my website, where it consists of 4x7 rows. Each cell will be a day on the Calendar and have an image representation. Normally I would just use an HTML table for this as its what I am familiar with, but would like to do this correctly and  do it with CSS.

I believe I will need 3 DIV's side by side, one to create the empty space on the left, one for empty space on the right and then a content (center) div for the calendar. What is the best way to create the actual cells for calendar though, where they are the same size and spaced equally apart in a 4x7 grid?

[image]

Comment: using tables doesn't make things "incorrect" in any way, use what you're comfortable with ;)

Comment: If you don't think of your calendar as tabular data, then you should go with CSS positioning. Also, what if you want to change your layout on various devices?

Comment: How is this calendar going to actually populate?

Comment: I will be manually populating it. The only change will be to the images every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here;

http://entio.pl/OBI_adwent/

images as far as i remember are just inside divs with float-left and margin: 2px 4px 2px 3pxl to give You 4 x 7 spaces applied :)